# $e.data() is not function WITH yii.confirm box

Tags: php, jquery, yii, yii2, bootbox

I have used following code for confirm box in yii 2(beta)

```
yii.allowAction = function ($e) {
    var message = $e.data('confirm');
    return message === undefined || yii.confirm(message, $e);
};
yii.confirm = function (message, $e) {
    bootbox.confirm(message, function (confirmed) {
        if (confirmed) {
            yii.handleAction($e);
        }
    });
    // confirm will always return false on the first call
    // to cancel click handler
    return false;
}
```

but after upgrading to yii 2 stable its stopped working

now I am getting error like:

$e.data() is not function

and i have checked that `seems the type of $e is a function !!!!`

Answer (score 1):

Yii official page said that Yii 2.0: Escape from Default's Yii2 Delete Confirm Box. If you want to use this, you can reference in  **[HERE](http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/654/escape-from-default-s-yii2-delete-confirm-box/)**

Comment: I have taken code from same page, but its not working my friend,that why i have posted code here,please have a look

Comment: I'm not pretty sure what you want. When I look around your issue, most of the people faced this problem. I think, it's not stable on Yii. Please take a look issue #18391 http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/654/escape-from-default-s-yii2-delete-confirm-box/#c18391. Otherwise, you can also use jQuery message box. Here is a link http://s3.envato.com/files/293712/index.html

Answer (score 0):

This is the code you need instead in your main.js to override the normal confirm and use bootbox instead.

```js
// override normal confirm and use bootbox for confirmation
yii.confirm = function (message, ok, cancel) {
  bootbox.confirm(message, function (confirmed) {
    if (confirmed) {
      !ok || ok();
    } else {
      !cancel || cancel();
    }
  });
}
```